# How to prove the following equation about $\tan^h(x)$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \tan^h x \, dx = \frac{tan^{h-1}\ x}{h-1} - \int \tan^{h-2} x \,dx$$
I just cannot find a way to somehow combine the two integral's result together....

Comment: The derivative of the right hand side is $\frac{\arctan^{h-2}x}{1+x^2}-\tan^{h-2}x$, which doesn't seem the same as $\tan^hx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Rewrite $\tan^h x$ as
$$\tan^{h-2} x(1+\tan^2 x)-\tan^{h-2} x$$
and split the integral in two.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int(\tan^h (x) + \tan^{h-2} (x) )dx =\int(\tan^{h-2}(x) \sec^2(x) dx \underbrace{=}_{u=\tan(x)} \int u^{h-2} du = \frac{u^{h-1}}{h-1}+C = \frac{\tan^{h-1}(x)}{h-1}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}
So your equation should be 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\tan^h (x) dx =\frac{\tan^{h-1}(x)}{h-1}-\int \tan^{h-2} (x) dx
\end{eqnarray*}